# DB2i doesn't update table

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, db2-400

I need to read a row from a table, change a value and update this row.
Hibernate Debug-Log says that it worked, but it didn't.
The database table entry is after the update the same as before.

Application:

```
    public int holeNeuNummer(String sa) throws WrappedException {
        int neueNummer = 0;

        Rggsnr rggsnr;
        try {
            rggsnr = Service.selectFirst("from Rggsnr where sa='" + sa + "'");
            System.out.println("OLD: " + rggsnr);
        } catch(DatabaseException | EmptyResultException e) {
            printError(e);
            return neueNummer;
        }

        rggsnr.getId().setLfdnr(rggsnr.getId().getLfdnr() + 1);

        // updaten
        try {
            Service.update(rggsnr);
            System.out.println("NEW: " + rggsnr);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return neueNummer;
    }
```

Output:

```
OLD: Rggsnr{sa=BH, lfdnr=867}
NEW: Rggsnr{sa=BH, lfdnr=868}
```

Hibernate Debug-Log of the UPDATE:

```
08:07:12,542 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl] - begin
08:07:12,542 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] - Obtaining JDBC connection
08:07:12,542 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] - Obtained JDBC connection
08:07:12,542 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction] - initial autocommit status: false
08:07:12,546 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl] - committing
08:07:12,546 DEBUG [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] - Processing flush-time cascades
08:07:12,547 DEBUG [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] - Dirty checking collections
08:07:12,550 DEBUG [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] - Flushed: 0 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
08:07:12,550 DEBUG [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
08:07:12,551 DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] - Listing entities:
08:07:12,551 DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] - net.oko.batch.persistence.dto.okod.Rggsnr{id=component[frei,jahr,lfdnr,sa]{frei=     , jahr=2019, sa=BH, lfdnr=868}}
08:07:12,551 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction] - committed JDBC Connection
08:07:12,552 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] - Releasing JDBC connection
08:07:12,552 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] - Released JDBC Connection
```

UPDATE function:

```
    public static void update(Object obj) throws DatabaseException {
        Session hsession = null;

        try {
            hsession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction htransaction = hsession.beginTransaction();
            hsession.update(obj);
            htransaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ex);
        } finally {
            if (hsession != null)
                hsession.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to show that code.
Non of the tables in the whole database has a primary key. So Rggsnr is a dummy class which says Annotations EmbeddedId and AttributeOverrides for all the columns. RggsnrId is an Embeddable class with the values.

Comment: Try catching *any*  / all exceptions, not only the types shown in your question.

Comment: I catch ```Throwable```, but there is never any Exception thrown. According to the Hibernate Debug-Log the UPDATE was successful. The DB2 database throws the update away and says it's all fine.

Comment: A jdbc trace may prove otherwise...

Comment: Verify the DB2 table is journaled, it is required when doing commitment control.  I would have expected an error if it wasn't but worth checking.

Comment: I'm wondering whether this is a library list problem, are you sure you don't have this table in multiple libraries, with the one you are checking subsequently not being the same as the one being updated? That would explain the lack of an exception. WRKF *ALL/RGGSNR should list whatever is present. Otherwise I would be looking at the commitment control situation, as others have suggested.